# Creating a tail and head in a list by value in C

Tags: c, list, pass-by-value

I want to create a list in C that the head and tail are NOT pointers, but a nodes by value. can it be done?

I want to use the head and the tail as an empty frame to put the list between. I do know how to create it as pointers and only want to know this because I just realise I don't know how to do this alone.

```
struct List{Node head, Node tail};
struct Node{struct Node* next, struct Node* prev, void* data};
```

Comment: Syntactically, you need to define `struct Node` completely and create `typedef struct Node Node;` before you create `struct List`.  To create a `List`, the compiler must know the size of a `Node`.

Comment: Ron are you asking about creating a **circular linked list** where the first node (is simply that the first node) and the last node is also simply a node (that points back to the first). This is indeed a valid alternative. You have 2 types of list. Non-circular (your normal HEAD/TAIL lists where HEAD/TAIL are just markers that do in some cases or don't hold data). Then you have a circular list where all nodes are equivalent data nodes with a pointer to next (in the case of a singly-linked list) or both a pointer to next/prev in the case of a double-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of the list with dummy head and tail (the way you presented here) is that you have no special cases in the list functions (insert, remove, ... etc).
Head and tail pointers make you take care of special cases in each function.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to have a **linked list**<sup>1</sup> of non pointer objects and it doesn't make sense at all, because the whole point of the list is that the `next` and `previous` members **POINT** to another instance of the same type, hence they **MUST BE** pointers.

---

[1]<sub>Single or Double linked list.</sub>

Comment: to have a node that point to the rest of the list but not as pointer to node but as a node that it will hold pointers in it.

List{
      Node   head; //the head and tail is node not a pointer
      Node   tail;
}

Node{
      Node*   next;
      Node*   prev;
      void*    data;
}

Comment: @RonAham Yes, that code will work. You just need to clear all the pointers to NULL, and then set `list.head.next=&list.tail` and `list.tail.prev=&list.head` to create an empty list.

Comment: You can create the equivalent of a linked list if you store the list in an array and record the index of the next or previous element in the list in the structure in lieu of pointers.  Further, you can reallocate the array without needing to adjust any of the list indices.  Hence: `struct Data { int next; int prev; void *data; };` and an array such as `struct Data data[1024];`.  Given  `struct Data *dp = &data[23];`, the next element in the list is `data[dp->next]` and the previous is `data[dp->prev]`.  Or, if you have `int idx = &data[23];`, the next element is `data[data[idx].next]`, etc.